# Spectral Irradiance of a Black Body

Tags: thermodynamics, conventions, thermal-radiation

[This](https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/blackbody-radiation) website states that the spectral irradiance of a Black Body is

$$F(\lambda) = \frac{2 \color{red}{\pi} h c^2}{\lambda^5 (\exp (hc/k\lambda T)-1)}.$$

[Other sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law), however, state that it is

$$F(\lambda) = \frac{2 h c^2}{\lambda^5 (\exp (hc/k\lambda T)-1)}.$$

Is the first source in error?

Answer (score 2):

The former is in Watts per meter squared per meter (spectral irradiance), while the latter is in Watts per square meter per meter per steradian (spectral radiance), and a surface sees $2\pi$ steradian.

In other words, the second expression should read:

$$\frac{dF(\lambda)}{d\Omega}= \cdots $$

where:

$$ F(\lambda) = \int_{\cos\theta=0}^{1}\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\frac{dF(\lambda)}{d\Omega}d(cos\theta)d\phi = \pi \frac{dF(\lambda)}{d\Omega}$$

Note the polar integral only covers the outward hemisphere (and there is an implicit $d(cos\theta) = \sin\theta d\theta$ weighting).

I work in this field and still need this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance#SI_radiometry_units

to keep it straight.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/863561/. ON second thought, there is a $\cos{\theta}$ dependence that I forgot. I'll fix it tomorrow.

Comment: From wiki: Spectral radiance expresses radiance as a function of frequency or wavelength. Radiance is the integral of the spectral radiance over all frequencies or wavelengths. For radiation emitted by the surface of an ideal black body at a given temperature, spectral radiance is governed by Planck's law, while the integral of its radiance, over the hemisphere into which its surface radiates, is given by the Stefan–Boltzmann law. Its surface is Lambertian, so that its radiance is uniform with respect to angle of view, and is simply the Stefan–Boltzmann integral divided by π. T

Comment: Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734636/spectral-irradiance-of-a-blackbody if you are interested

Answer (score 1):

The latter is a specific intensity (or spectral radiance) and the former is the flux from a surface (spectral irradiance). If the specific intensity of a blackbody (i.e. the Planck function) is $B(\lambda)$ in units of W per unit area, per unit wavelength, per steradian of solid angle; then the flux from a uniformly bright surface is $\pi B$ in units of W per unit area, per unit wavelength.

The factor of $\pi$ arises by integrating $\cos \theta$ over a hemispherical solid angle - because specific intensity is a directional quantity.
$$\int^{2\pi}_{\phi=0} \int^{\pi/2}_{\theta=0} \cos\theta \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi = \pi.$$

As far as I can see, that is exactly what the sources you point to have said.

Comment: @Jbag1212 the brightness of a blackbody surface is independent of how far away you are from it or at what angle it is viewed.

Comment: @Jbag1212 the formula *you* have presented and asked about because you don't understand what it is, is the surface brightness of a blackbody. Notice how the distance to the source does not feature in that equation.

Comment: The surface brightness of a resolved object is independent of distance. A blackbody is, by definition, in thermal equilibrium and absorbs exactly what it emits at every wavelength.  If you know the answers, why ask a question? https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/blackbody-radiation

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734636/spectral-irradiance-of-a-blackbody if you are interested