# Spectral Irradiance of a Blackbody

Tags: conventions, thermal-radiation, radiometry

[This](https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/blackbody-radiation) website states that the spectral irradiance of a Black Body is

$$F(\lambda) = \frac{2 \pi h c^2}{\lambda^5 (\exp (hc/k\lambda T)-1)}.$$

What does it mean to talk about "the" spectral irradiance of a blackbody?
[image: By CMGLee Wikimedia Commons]

I can understand the radiant flux, radiant intensity, radiant exitance, and radiance of a blackbody. The radiant flux would be the total power emitted by a particular black body. The radiant intensity would be the radiant flux per unit steradian. The radiant exitance would be the radiant flux per unit *area of the black body itself.* The radiance would be the radiant exitance per unit steradian, or equivalently the radiant intensity per unit area of the black body itself.

The corresponding spectral unit for each of these would be per wavelength (or frequency).

But the (spectral) **ir**radiance is a measurement of the flux through an area of size $A$, divided by that area $A$. Suppose I had a spherical black body of uniform radiant exitance, and a detector which measured electromagnetic flux. The flux that this detector measures will depend on how close I am to the black body, and also the angle of the detector with respect to the normal.

So again, how is it even possible to talk about **the** spectral irradiance of a Black Body?

(Image by CMGLee, Wikimedia Commons)

Comment: I think your link is just... wrong.  That equation looks suspiciously like the one for spectral _radiance_.  You can start at Wikipedia's [Planck's Law entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#The_law), and compare to your link.  And yes, irradiance is better thought of from the perspective of the geometry (Area) being illuminated, rather than a property of the object(s) illuminating it.