# Why does the spectral radiance not depend on source density?

Tags: thermal-radiation

The spectral radiance as discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734236/spectral-irradiance-of-a-black-body) is certainly correct, but I fail to apply it to my problem.

**Problem**: I want to calculate the SR of a gas (given temperature, density and target wavelength) and fail to understand why it does not depend on density.

**Explanation**: The radiation source can be viewed as a superposition of many small radiators (here: molecules). The far field is then the sum of all contributions, which leads to a continuum in significantly large distance. Thus, the SR must depend on density. We can also turn this around and go to very low densities, where the number of radiating molecules per unit area decreases and thus the overall radiated power must as well.

Where is the error in my explanation? I know it is there, but I fail to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on [optical depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_depth). For a radiator at thermal equilibrium with an optical depth >>1, you get a blackbody spectrum.

The solar chromosphere has a lower temperature than the photosphere. At most wavelengths, it has a low optical depth, so the photospheric radiation (approximately a blackbody spectrum) shines through. However, at certain wavelengths, it has high optical depth. At these wavelengths, it absorbs radiation from the photosphere, and we see the famous [Fraunhofer lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_lines) in the spectrum.

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing piece of information. Basically the linked answer is for optically thick sources only, and would need the optical thickness involved to be general.